# Drag and drop - UIGestureRecognizer - View added not where I want to

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have this 2 tableViews (All Services available and service offered) in a splitViewController. The idea is that then the cell is moved across the center of the screen, it moves to the service offered table view. 
Everything works except then the touch `.began, the cell is being added to the top of the tableView covering the navBar.
[image]

On `.changed` it follows my finger
[image]

I would like the view/cell to be added where the touch began, on top of the "ServiceCell" I am touching. I tried adding it to the `splitViewController.view` but I think there is something wrong with my logic.

Here the code:

```
func didLongPressCell (gr: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let serviceCell:ServiceCell =  gr.view as! ServiceCell
    switch gr.state {
    case .began:

        let touchOffsetInCell = gr.location(in: gr.view)
        let dragEvent = DragganbleServiceCell()
        mDraggableServiceCell = dragEvent.makeWithServiceCell(serviceCell: serviceCell, offset: self.tableView.contentOffset, touchOffset: touchOffsetInCell)
        self.splitViewController?.view.addSubview(mDraggableServiceCell!)

    case .changed:
        let cp:CGPoint = gr.location(in: self.view)
        let newOrigin = CGPoint(x: (cp.x), y: (cp.y) - (mDraggableServiceCell?.touchOffset?.y)!)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
            self.mDraggableServiceCell?.frame = CGRect(origin: newOrigin, size: (self.mDraggableServiceCell?.frame.size)!)  
        })

    case .ended:
        let detailViewNC = self.splitViewController?.viewControllers[1] as! UINavigationController
        let detailView = detailViewNC.topViewController as! ServiceOfferedTableViewController
        if (mDraggableServiceCell?.frame.intersects(detailView.tableView.frame))! {

        onDragEnded(serviceCell:serviceCell)
        }else{

        mDraggableServiceCell?.removeFromSuperview()

        }
    default:
        print("Any other action?")
    }
}
```

In `DraggableServiceCell`:

```
class DragganbleServiceCell: ServiceCell {

    var originalPosition:CGPoint?
    var touchOffset:CGPoint?

    func makeWithServiceCell(serviceCell:ServiceCell, offset:CGPoint, touchOffset:CGPoint)->DragganbleServiceCell{

        let newFrame =  CGRect(x: serviceCell.frame.origin.x, y: serviceCell.frame.origin.y, width: serviceCell.frame.size.width, height: serviceCell.frame.size.height)
        let dragCell = DragganbleServiceCell(frame: newFrame)
       dragCell.touchOffset = touchOffset
        dragCell.service = serviceCell.service
        dragCell.serviceName.text = serviceCell.service?.service_description
        return dragCell
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.containingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(230, green: 32, blue: 31)
        self.serviceName.textColor = .white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in `makeWithServiceCell(serviceCell:ServiceCell, offset:CGPoint, touchOffset:CGPoint) -> DragganbleServiceCell`. The frame of your `serviceCell` is relative to the `tableView` that contains it instead of `UISplitViewController`'s view and you are never using the `offset` or `touchOffset` values to correct that. So try adjusting the frame in the same way you are doing it in the `.changed` event.

You might even find that the `convert(_:to:)` method on `UIView` might be useful to do `CGPoint` transformations between two views. See more details [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622504-convert).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding the gesture to `self.splitViewController?.view` instead of `self.view`if you are not doing and changing this part of the code.

```
case .changed:
    let cp:CGPoint = gr.location(in: self.view)
    let newOrigin = CGPoint(x: (cp.x), y: (cp.y) - (mDraggableServiceCell?.touchOffset?.y)!)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.mDraggableServiceCell?.frame = CGRect(origin: newOrigin, size: (self.mDraggableServiceCell?.frame.size)!)  
    })
```

to this

```
case .changed:
    let cp:CGPoint = gr.location(in: self.splitViewController?.view)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1, animations: {
        self.mDraggableServiceCell?.center = cp  
    })
```

try once.

Comment: thanks but the gesture is added to the cell. Furthermore `.changed` works as it was supposed to. The problem is in `.begin`